# Prepend a string to function result

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT:
As an exercise I need to prepend a string to the result of a function that will be defined in a second moment. I though about using a decorator and I was clearly wrong; any suggestion on how to do it?

OLD:

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return "hello {0}".format(func(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped

@my_decorator
def myfunc():
    return "boy"

def myfunc():
    return "girl"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(myfunc())
```

This code will print "girl", I would like it to print "hello girl".
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Why are you overriding the first definition? The solution to your problem will probably be along the lines of not doing that. Decorators don't work the way you're trying to get them to work.

Comment: You can't. You can replace objects at any time, and you did so here. You'll have to re-apply a decorator at the time you replace the name, or when you call the object.

Comment: I'm doing it as an exercise. I need to prepend a string to the result of a function that will be defined in a second moment. I though about using a decorator and I was clearly wrong; I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

A decorator replaces the function with a wrapped version. If you then replace it again, the decorated version is gone.

Really you shouldn't do this. But bear in mind that the decorator is just a wrapper; if you are going to be replacing functions dynamically, then don't decorate them in the first place, just apply the wrapper when you call it:

```
print(my_decorator(myfunc)())
```

Comment: thanks, so using a decorator is the wrong approach for what I need to do, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Your decorator works if you explicitly apply it to the redefined function, as others have mentioned:

```
@my_decorator
def myfunc():
    return "boy"

@my_decorator
def myfunc():
    return "girl"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    print(myfunc())
```

If you can't do that statically, you can still use your decorator code to do it functionlly:

```
def myfunc():
    return "spot"

myfunc = my_decorator(myfunc)
```